Apache CXF and ODATA
I am fairly new to Apache CXF and odata. I'm trying to implement ODATA with Apache CXF.
When I try to hit the http://localhost:8080/hello I get 404 not found error. but it doesn't show any error in the ide console. Anyone have any idea?
I have started with creating a CXF project. below mentioned are my classes.
@Configuration
public class CxfConfig {

    @Autowired
    private HelloService helloService;

    @Bean
    public JAXRSServerFactoryBean jaxRsServerFactoryBean() {
        JAXRSServerFactoryBean factoryBean = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setServiceBean(helloService);
        factoryBean.setAddress("/hello");```

        return factoryBean;
    }
}

@Service
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloService {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain") // what is the output. here itzs produces text
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello, CXF!";
    }
}


Are you sure the service is being hosted a port 8080?

yes. In my console Its logging Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path ''
